# Validate proxy URL using XML regex pattern

Tags: xml, regex, url

I am using the **XML regex pattern** to match my proxy URL.

eg: Proxy : ab-proxy-sample.company.com:8080

My requirement :

1. Should **not** begin with **http://** OR **https://** (Match the whole word)
2. Should accept any string + a port
3. Should accept even strings starting with **ht**

My current XML regex is : [^http://|https://].+:[0-9]+|

But its matching each letter instead of the whole word ?

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Using `[]` means that you match any character. Your regex says: do not match any of those characters: `:/|htp`. Use negative lookahead to not-match complete words.

Comment: Hi arnep... Thanks! I am fairly new to this. What do you mean by a negative lookaheaed? Could you please give me an example ?  (I want to avoid the whole word http:// or https://)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @arnep points out, you're attempting to use [a negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) with [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html), which isn't the way it works.  Also, here is some information regarding [lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

I'm sure someone else will post an answer you can copy and paste, but this is a useful opportunity to learn the basics of regex!

**UPDATE:**

I didn't realize that you were using an engine that doesn't support negative lookarounds.  Without negative lookarounds, it's nearly impossible to achieve what you're trying to do.

*Nearly* ;)

Here is a "brute-force" combinatoric method of doing it:

```
(?:[^h]|h(?:[^t]|t(?:[^t]|t(?:[^p]|p(?:[^s:]|s(?:[^:]|:(?:[^\/]|\/(?:[^\/])))|:(?:[^\/]|\/(?:[^\/])))))))\S+:\d+
```

1. If the XML engine doesn't support non-captured groups, i.e. `(?: ... )` then use regular groups instead:

   ```
   ([^h]|h([^t]|t([^t]|t([^p]|p([^s:]|s([^:]|:([^\/]|\/([^\/])))|:([^\/]|\/([^\/])))))))\S+:\d+
   ```
2. If the XML engine doesn't support characters classes like `\S` and `\d` then use `[^ \t\r\n\p]` and `[0-9]` instead.

Here is a running example: http://rubular.com/r/JnpCVgeLmL.  Try changing the test string.  You'll see that...

```
    ab-proxy-sample.company.com:8080          # matches
    htab-proxy-sample.company.com:8080        # matches
    http://ab-proxy-sample.company.com:8080   # doesn't
    https://ab-proxy-sample.company.com:8080  # doesn't
    httpd://ab-proxy-sample.company.com:8080  # matches
```

Note that *you do not need the `^` and `$`*.  I added these specifically for the Rubular demo, but apparently the XML engine assumes this condition (anchored-ness).

How does this work?  It's easier to understand if we break it up like this:

```
    ([^h] | h
    ([^t] | t
    ([^t] | t
    ([^p] | p
    ([^s:]| s ([^:]|:([^\/]|\/([^\/])))
          | :        ([^\/]|\/([^\/])))
    ))))
    \S+:\d+
```

The explanation:

1. If the first char isn't an "h", then great!  (The string can't possibly be "http://" or "https://".)
2. If the first char *is* an "h" though, then:

   1. If the second char isn't a "t", then great!  (The string can't possibly be "http://" or "https://".)
   2. If the second char *is* a "t" though, then:

      1. ... isn't "t", great!
      2. ... *is* "t", then:

         1. ... isn't "p", great!
         2. ... *is* "p", then:

Here, it gets tricky: now we encounter *three* branches.

1. If the fifth char isn't an "s" nor a ":", then great!
2. If the fifth char *is* an "s" though, then:

   1. If the sixth char isn't a ":", then great!
   2. If the sixth char *is* a ":" though, then:

      1. If the seventh char isn't a "/", then great!
      2. If the seventh char *is* a "/" though, then:

         1. If the eighth char isn't a "/", then great!
         2. Otherwise, fail!  We found an "https://".
3. If the fifth char *is* a ":" though, then:

   1. If the sixth char isn't a "/", then great!
   2. If the sixth char *is* a "/" though, then:

      1. If the seventh char isn't a "/", then great!
      2. Otherwise, fail!  We found an "http://".

And finally, if we've gotten this far, then we look for a string of non-whitespace characters, followed by a colon, followed by a string of digits.

I leave it to a smarter mathematician than myself to ponder whether all strings matchable using lookarounds can be "brute-forced" in such a way.

Comment: Here's some hints though.  ``.+`` matches whitespace too.  You may want to consider ``\S+`` instead.  You've got the ``[0-9]+`` right, although it can be shortened to ``\d+``.

Comment: Hi acheong87...thanks for your help. But as per http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html, XML does not support negative lookahead... Is there any other alternative ?

Comment: @simplysiby - I've updated my solution.  Please give it a try and let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer !! I had to remove escape for the forward slash. Its finally working with : `([^h]|h([^t]|t([^t]|t([^p]|p([^s:]|s([^:]|:([^/]|/([^/])))|:([^/]|/([^/])))))))\S+:\d+`  . Thanks again !!

Answer (score 0):

To avoid matching a string starting with some word, use negative look ahead:

```
^(?!https?).*$
```

will match any strings that do not start with http(s). The other requirements are left to the reader as an exercise :-)

Comment: Hi Arnep, Thanks for your help.... but I am using XML regex pattern and this is not supported.

Comment: @simplysiby I don't know "XML regex pattern", do you have more information about that?