# How to emulate a negative lookbehind assertions in Qt regexp?

Tags: c++, regex, qt

I am writing a program using Qt 4.6 and I need to capture all occurences of non-range literals from expressions like 
`"SUM(A1:A3)+B1-B3+SUM(D1:D3)/COUNT(D1:D3)"`,
i.e. B1, B3, but not A1, A3, D1, D3. I have tried to use QRegExp, but it doesn't support negative lookbehind assertions, so I can't exclude literals like A3, D3.
My regexp `(?<!:)([A-Z]{1,4}[1-9]\\d{0,3})(?!:)` doesn't work. 
I need your input. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you could use

```
(?:^|[^:])\b([A-Z]{1,4}[1-9]\d{0,3})\b(?!:)
```

The first group matches the empty string at the beginning or any character except the colon.  I also added *word boundaries* `\b` so that the pattern won't match things like `A4a`.

Often times it is simpler to write "positive" patterns.  For example, using

```
(...)(:...)?
```

with `...` denoting your `[A-Z]` pattern to match cell references, you can match ranges and non-ranges in one pass, then discard all ranges when looping over the results.  You can easily detect whether a match is a range by checking if the second capture group is empty.

Comment: I've retrofitted a pattern in a "positive" manner and it works fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For solutions that require lookarounds on engines that don't support lookarounds, I have found only one alternative: "combinatoric brute-forcing" as I call it, though I'm sure there's a more technical name.  One example is here: [Validate proxy URL using XML regex pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11157914/validate-proxy-url-using-xml-regex-pattern/11158330#11158330).

But *it doesn't work when you need to find more than one occurrence*.  You've probably tried something like this yourself:

```
/[^:]\b([A-Z]{1,4}[1-9]\d{0,3})\b[^:]/
```

(I added the `\b` to be more safe.  Also, remember to escape the backslashes again.)

And if you did try this, then you notice the [problem](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%5B%5E:%5D%5Cb%28%5BA-Z%5D%7B1,4%7D%5B1-9%5D%5Cd%7B0,3%7D%29%5Cb%5B%5E:%5D&input=SUM%28A1:A3%29%2bB1-B3%2bSUM%28D1:D3%29%2bA2%2bB1:B3/COUNT%28D1:D3%29): the first match is found after reading up to `+B1-`; so, since the `-` has already been read, the next cell reference `B3` cannot be matched, since there is no appropriate character for `[^:]`.

To redescribe the problem, the above regex can only catch every other match in a consecutive chain of cell references, e.g. for the string,

```
(A1+A2+A3+A4+A5+A6)/(B1+B2+B3+B4+B5+B6)
^^^^  ^^^^  ^^^^    ^^^^  ^^^^  ^^^^
```

...only the indicated parts will match, also shown [here](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%5B%5E:%5D%5Cb%28%5BA-Z%5D%7B1,4%7D%5B1-9%5D%5Cd%7B0,3%7D%29%5Cb%5B%5E:%5D&input=%28A1%2bA2%2bA3%2bA4%2bA5%2bA6%29/%28B1%2bB2%2bB3%2bB4%2bB5%2bB6%29).

There is no way to get around this in a single regex.  Your alternatives:

1. Use a non-regex approach.
2. If you *must* use regex for some reason, then probably your only hope is to be able to use at least *two* regexes (e.g. use the first to insert spaces around all cell-reference-like strings, so that you have no consecutive chains of cell references).
3. Or, in the improbable case that it's good enough to capture them into submatches, i.e. accessible via `.cap(1)`, `.cap(2)`, etc. you may be able to do the following.

---

```
/[^:]\b([A-Z]{1,4}[1-9]\d{0,3})\b[^:](?:(\b([A-Z]{1,4}[1-9]\d{0,3})\b[^:](?:(\b([A-Z]{1,4}[1-9]\d{0,3})\b[^:](?:(\b([A-Z]{1,4}[1-9]\d{0,3})\b[^:](?:(\b([A-Z]{1,4}[1-9]\d{0,3})\b[^:](?:(\b([A-Z]{1,4}[1-9]\d{0,3})\b[^:](?:(\b([A-Z]{1,4}[1-9]\d{0,3})\b[^:]))?))?))?))?))?))?/
```

Well, that's impossible to read, so here's a more readable version.  Pretend `XY` expands to our cell reference expression, `\b([A-Z]{1,4}[1-9]\d{0,3})\b`.  Then, the above is the same as:

```
/[^:]XY[^:](?:(XY[^:](?:(XY[^:](?:(XY[^:](?:(XY[^:](?:(XY[^:]))?))?))?))?))?))?/
```

See the pattern?  Before we go further, you can see that [this regex matches our example perfectly](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%5B%5E%3A%5D%5Cb(%5BA-Z%5D%7B1%2C4%7D%5B1-9%5D%5Cd%7B0%2C3%7D)%5Cb%5B%5E%3A%5D(%3F%3A(%5Cb(%5BA-Z%5D%7B1%2C4%7D%5B1-9%5D%5Cd%7B0%2C3%7D)%5Cb%5B%5E%3A%5D(%3F%3A(%5Cb(%5BA-Z%5D%7B1%2C4%7D%5B1-9%5D%5Cd%7B0%2C3%7D)%5Cb%5B%5E%3A%5D(%3F%3A(%5Cb(%5BA-Z%5D%7B1%2C4%7D%5B1-9%5D%5Cd%7B0%2C3%7D)%5Cb%5B%5E%3A%5D(%3F%3A(%5Cb(%5BA-Z%5D%7B1%2C4%7D%5B1-9%5D%5Cd%7B0%2C3%7D)%5Cb%5B%5E%3A%5D(%3F%3A(%5Cb(%5BA-Z%5D%7B1%2C4%7D%5B1-9%5D%5Cd%7B0%2C3%7D)%5Cb%5B%5E%3A%5D(%3F%3A(%5Cb(%5BA-Z%5D%7B1%2C4%7D%5B1-9%5D%5Cd%7B0%2C3%7D)%5Cb%5B%5E%3A%5D))%3F))%3F))%3F))%3F))%3F))%3F&input=(A1%2BA2%2BA3%2BA4%2BA5%2BA6)%2F(B1%2BB2%2BB3%2BB4%2BB5%2BB6)).  The drawback is that you can only handle a chain of consecutive cell references as long as you define your regex.  The above can handle 7, and beyond that it [breaks](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%5B%5E:%5D%5Cb%28%5BA-Z%5D%7B1,4%7D%5B1-9%5D%5Cd%7B0,3%7D%29%5Cb%5B%5E:%5D%28%5Cb%28%5BA-Z%5D%7B1,4%7D%5B1-9%5D%5Cd%7B0,3%7D%29%5Cb%5B%5E:%5D%28%5Cb%28%5BA-Z%5D%7B1,4%7D%5B1-9%5D%5Cd%7B0,3%7D%29%5Cb%5B%5E:%5D%28%5Cb%28%5BA-Z%5D%7B1,4%7D%5B1-9%5D%5Cd%7B0,3%7D%29%5Cb%5B%5E:%5D%28%5Cb%28%5BA-Z%5D%7B1,4%7D%5B1-9%5D%5Cd%7B0,3%7D%29%5Cb%5B%5E:%5D%28%5Cb%28%5BA-Z%5D%7B1,4%7D%5B1-9%5D%5Cd%7B0,3%7D%29%5Cb%5B%5E:%5D%28%5Cb%28%5BA-Z%5D%7B1,4%7D%5B1-9%5D%5Cd%7B0,3%7D%29%5Cb%5B%5E:%5D%29?%29?%29?%29?%29?%29?&input=%28A1%2bA2%2bA3%2bA4%2bA5%2bA6%2bA7%2bA8%29/%28B1%2bB2%2bB3%2bB4%2bB5%2bB6%2bB7%2bB8%29).

Comment: Ah, I should have checked that Qt supports look-_aheads_, before posting this solution.  I misunderstood.  :)

Answer (score 0):

QRegularExpression in Qt 5.0 supports (fixed length) lookbehind assertions.

https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-2371 was closed on Mar 22,2012. Qt 5.0 was released on Dec 19,2012.